# UIslider Value problem

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, uislider

I have a slider in tableview.In slider Action method I do some calculation and get Table reloaded.When table reload second time it set the slider value to its minimum value.
Can anybody know  why this strange problem is happening.
Thanks in advance!

### Code:

```
- (IBAction)sliderAction:(id)sender
{
    UISlider* durationSlider = sender;
    float gmval,finalCalculationValue;  
    float tempgmValue=[self.gmValue floatValue];
    gmval=durationSlider.value;
    tempgmValue=gmval/tempgmValue;
    finalCalculationValue=tempgmValue/100;
    tempgmValue=finalCalculationValue*[self.gmValue floatValue];
    self.gmValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f",tempgmValue];
    self.label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",tempgmValue];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tbleView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
                                            UITableViewCell *cell;

UILabel *label                              


cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
cell = [self reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier withIndexPath:indexPath];
}
    return cell;
}
                            }
-(UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
CGRect cellRectangle;
cellRectangle = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 100);

UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
UILabel *label1;                    
cellRectangle = CGRectMake(15.0, 50, 200, 20.0);
label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle];
label1.tag = 5;                             label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[label1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label1];
[label1 release];                                   


UISlider *gmSlider=[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 20, 180, 21)];    gmSlider.tag=2003;                                     gmSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  

   gmSlider.continuous = YES;
    gmSlider.minimumValue=10;
                                gmSlider.maximumValue=200;                              gmSlider.value=@"100";                                  [gmSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];  
    [cell.contentView addSubview:gmSlider];
    }
    return cell;                                 
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is basically with tableView if I do not write tableView reloadData it is working fine.

Comment: Can you post the code in cellForRowAtIndex: method?

Comment: @iPhone Pgr  I have posted code for cellForRowAtIndexPath and reuseCell methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your methods... and seems to work fine for me... check it on your side...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    UILabel *label                              ;
    CGRect cellRectangle;
    cellRectangle = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 100);


    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [self reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier withIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    for (UIView * view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        view = nil;
    }
    UILabel *label1;                    
    cellRectangle = CGRectMake(15.0, 50, 200, 20.0);
    label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle];
    label1.tag = 5;                             label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [label1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];
    [label1 release];                                   
    UISlider *gmSlider=[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 20, 180, 21)];    gmSlider.tag=2003;                                     gmSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  

    gmSlider.continuous = YES;
    gmSlider.minimumValue=10;
    gmSlider.maximumValue=200;                              
    gmSlider.value=100.0;                                  
    [gmSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];  
    [cell.contentView addSubview:gmSlider];

    return cell;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGRect cellRectangle;
    cellRectangle = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 100);

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];



return cell;                                 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It'd help if you'd show your code for -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, but an educated guess is that the trouble is in that method. People often forget that as soon as a cell scrolls off the screen, it becomes available for reuse. Also, because cells are reused, they have to be configured each time in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. That method should look something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:someIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] init...];
        [cell autorelease];  // autorelease here to balance alloc
        // Don't set the cell up in here or you'll have problems!
    }
    // Set the cell up here so that you handle both the new cell and the reuse cases.
    cell.sliderValue = [self sliderValueAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.label = [self labelForValueAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // ...and so on....

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are setting the  value of the slider each time cell reloads `gmSlider.value=@"100";`. You have set the value as the newly calculated value rather than a constant 100.